# STL vector operator data

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I was just reading about vectors when i came across the data operator.In below example data operator is being used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector (5);

  int* p = myvector.data();

  *p = 10;
  ++p;
  *p = 20;
  p[2] = 100;

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<myvector.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
myvector contains: 10 20 0 100 0
```

My question is  why 0 at the place 0f 100 and 100 is moved one location backward.
as:

1. `p` is equivalent `myvector[0]` which is given value `10`.
2. `++p;` now `p` points to `myvector[1]` given value `20`
3. so after `20`, `100` should come so why there is `0`.

Comment: This is more about the pointer arithmetic than the `.data()` member of `vector`.

Comment: I think the confusion arises from using the pointer `p` for two different purposes. As an "array" and as an "iterator".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you already mutated `p` when you did

```
++p
```

So this operation

```
p[2]
```

is already offset by 1 index so it is as if you did

```
p[2 + 1]
```

from the **original** address of `p`

Comment: is it specific for vector that index is offset because in C if we do this thing with array,everything works fine.

Comment: @PaulSen `++p` introduces the additional offset

Comment: @PaulSen This has nothing to do with `std::vector` specifically, as soon as you accessed the raw array using `data` typical array and pointer semantics are in play.

Comment: @PaulSen Doing "this thing" with an array - `int c[5] = {0}; int* p = c; *p = 10; ++p; *p = 20; p[2] = 100;` - will produce exactly the same result.